# How do I create a char** type of variable using structs

Tags: c, struct

I'm currently learning about structs in C and I'm having some problems working with structs and arrays, I'm need to create a code that uses a struct that contains a char** variable, and then I need to use that struct to create two char** strings and use them for storing some strings.

Sadly I couldn't manage to create those two char** strings. can you guys help me out?

P.S: If you can explain to me how to use structs with arrays and dynamic arrays/strings i would be very pleased, i need to understand that for another question :)

This is what I've done already:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 4
#define MIN 1

typedef struct lists
{
    char** reasons;
}lists;

int welcomeAndInput(char** pros, char** cons);
void addCon(char** cons);
void addPro(char** pros);

int main(void)
{
    int result = 1;
    lists cons = { (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1) };
    lists pros = { (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1) }; 
    while (result != 0)
    {
        result = welcomeAndInput(pros, cons);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int welcomeAndInput(char** pros, char** cons)
{
    int result = 0;
    printf("Choose an option: \n");
    printf("1: Add a PRO reason \n");
    printf("2: Add a CON reason \n");
    printf("3: Print your reasons\n");
    printf("4: Exit \n");
    scanf("%d", &result);
    getchar();
    while (result != 0)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                addPro(pros);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                addCon(cons);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                while (result < MIN || result > MAX)
                {
                    printf("Enter a valid input!");
                    scanf("%d", &result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void addPro(char** pros)
{

}

void addCon(char** cons)
```

Thanks!

P.S -V2: So I've noticed that i actually gave you the wrong code, here is the code with everything that i did manage to do. I know that the welcomeAndInput calling is wrong :)

Comment: well maybe u should try to compile your code, then you will notice, that 
 "lists cons = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1);"
makes no sence.

Comment: Oh yea i forgot to mention that you should ignore it lol

Comment: Which two char** strings are you talking about?

Comment: The statement `result = welcomeAndInput` copies the address of the function to the `result` variable. It is not calling the function `welcomeAndInput` and returning a value. You should be replacing the statement with `result = welcomeAndInput();`

Comment: I edited the question, I posted the wrong version of the code, sorry :(

Comment: What is your plan of the data structure that the program should build? Should the `pros` and `cons` point to an array of `char*`? Each array member points to an entry? What about the actual number of entries that will be added by `addPro`? I think you will definitely benefit from a clean design.

Answer (score 0):

I just add few stuffs and its not the complete solution but it will help you to solve your solution, i didn't free any the allocated memories, you can post the final/completed solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 4
#define MIN 1

typedef struct list
{
    char** reason;
}lists;

int welcomeAndInput(lists *pros, lists* cons);
//void addCon(char** cons);
//void addPro(char** pros);
void addreason(lists* pros);

int main(void)
{
    int result = 1;
    lists cons = { (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1) };
    lists pros = { (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1) };


    while (result != 0)
    {
        result = welcomeAndInput(&pros, &cons);
    }
        printf("reason : %s \n",pros.reason[0] );

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int welcomeAndInput(lists *pros, lists* cons)
{
    int result = 0;
    printf("Choose an option: \n");
    printf("1: Add a PRO reason \n");
    printf("2: Add a CON reason \n");
    printf("3: Print your reasons\n");
    printf("4: Exit \n");
    scanf("%d", &result);
    //getchar();
    //while (result != 0)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                addreason(pros);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                addreason(cons);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
            default:
            //{
            //    while (result < MIN || result > MAX)
                //{
                    printf("Invalid input!");
              //      scanf("%d", &result);
                //}
            //}*/
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void addreason(lists* pros)
{
    char *reason = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    int count=0;
        printf("enter reason :");
        getchar();
            while (count <256){

                reason[count]=getchar();
                if ('\n' == reason[count])
                    break;
                count++;
            }

//fgets(reason, 256, stdin);//   
     pros->reason[0]=reason;
}
```